# I need advice on creating a save system?

Tags: java, save

So far i am making a game that you play and then every five seconds it saves the game. so far I have an ok save system. what happens is say you had 100 wood and 30 bread and 0 dirt then it would save to a file "100 30 0". every time you start up the app it loads the save by:

```
public static void loadSave(File loadPath){

    try{
    Scanner loadScanner = new Scanner(loadPath);

    while(loadScanner.hasNext()){
        for (int i = 0; i < ldStr.length; i++) {
            ldStr[i] = loadScanner.nextInt();
            if(i == 7){
                Print();
            }
        }
    }


    loadScanner.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

After that it puts them into variables in my main class, like this:

```
public static void Print(){
    System.out.println("Loaded File. These are the values: " + ldStr[0] + " " + ldStr[1] + " " + ldStr[2] + " " + ldStr[3] + " " + ldStr[4] + " " + ldStr[5] + " " + ldStr[6]);

    Pane.numberOfChopers = ldStr[0];
    if(ldStr[0] > 0){
        Pane.boughtChoper = true;
        Pane.isChoping = true;
    }
    Pane.numberOfHuts = ldStr[1];
    if(ldStr[1] > 0){
        Pane.boughtHut = true;
        Pane.isRenting = true;
    }
    Pane.resMoney = ldStr[2];
    Pane.resWood = ldStr[3];
    Pane.hutCostMoney = ldStr[4];
    Pane.hutCostWood = ldStr[5];
    Pane.chopperPrice = ldStr[6];
    Pane.numberOfPeople = ldStr[7];
}
```

Anyway I am just wondering if this is efficient. Also if I were to create a login system how could I go about saving the values to their name(would creating a separate file for each player be ok).

ps. I don't plan to use SQL

Comment: @mitchWheat if your talking about how I spelt it wrong I did that on accident and was too lazy to fix it.

Comment: The answer would depend on how much work you want to go to, for example I might use an XML file to achieve the same thing, it's generally easier to parse, but the amount of overhead needed to get it started and work is not insignificant

Comment: A serialized HashMap or custom class would be easy to implement and extend later. But this question is off topic for StackOverflow. You should ask for general advice on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or ask for people to look at your stuff at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @indivisible - never, ever, under any circumstances, use java serialization for persistence (==long term storage). it is VERY unfriendly to future refactorings (unless you really know what youre doing)

Comment: Belongs to Gamedev.SE ..........

Comment: @radai, I only suggested it as an easy to implement solution although updating wouldn't be too difficult as long as you track and handle versions correctly but I see your point. If you want a flat file then JSON or YAML would fit quite nicely and not have as much overhead as XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a separate file for every player I would use this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Login {

static String   playerName;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    playerName = "John"; //set playerName to the name of the player
    createFile();
}

public static void createFile() {

    File f = new File("res/" + playerName + ".txt");
    if (!f.exists())
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public static String getSavePath(){
        return "res/" + playerName + ".txt";


}

}
```

Replace **`"res/"`**`+ playerName + ".txt"` with the name of the folder(or path) where the save
file should be created.